# How can i disable analyzer suppression for custom analyzers in VisualStudio?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

Contrary to many requests, which seek to disable analyzer warnings i am trying something different here - I've written a ConfigureAwait-Analyzer, to force developers to specify configureawait in tools librarys to prevent async deadlocks.

The analyzer is in the category "Error" instead of Warning - There is just one particular issue. VisualStudio offers to suppress this analyzer, which i obviously don't want to be an option for an error.

How can i influence (turn off) this behaviour?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. You could create an anlyzer to look for the supression but hat one can be suppressed too. Also, don't forget that your users always have the option not to use your analyzer at all. They are in control of their source code, not you.

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Through using source control i can prevent someone from doing such changes. I can't influence what they press in their IDE though

Comment: It sounds like you want to prevent people from checking in bad code. Typically this would be solved by running the analyzers on a continuous integration (CI) server. You would reject code changes that failed your CI checks.

Comment: If you have control over their source control server, you have control over their source code. Run the analyzers on the CI server. Scan the code for suppressions on a regular basis. Other than that, use traditional HR methods to make your employees do what you want them to do. And if they refuse to, you can always terminate their employment ;-) Joking aside, what I'm saying is that this is not a _technical_ problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private static DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Error,
        isEnabledByDefault: true,
        description: Description,
        customTags: new[] { WellKnownDiagnosticTags.NotConfigurable });
```